# How to make <area tag hotspot show color

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use area tag to make some hotspots for an email template. But the point is I cant see where these hotspots are. Can I atleast assign some colors to these boxes while working and then I can just remove them when I am done. This is what I have. I just need to see them while creating the template.

```
<map name="0.1_Map3"> 
<area href="" shape="rect" coords="38,19,110,35" target="_blank"> 
<area href="" shape="rect" coords="134,19,254,34" target="_blank"> 
<area href="" shape="rect" coords="278,17,388,35" target="_blank"> 
<area href="" shape="rect" coords="406,18,510,36" target="_blank"> 
<area href="" shape="rect" coords="534,20,664,35" target="_blank"> 
</map>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this tool can help you to define your map http://codecanyon.net/item/html5-canvas-image-mapper/3172058